# Factory pattern cyclic dependency

Tags: c#, asp.net, factory-pattern

I'm working on a Web API 2.0 project and suspect I'm doing something monumentally wrong with a ModelFactory class.

I'm attempting to implement factory 'Create' methods for constructing and returning sanitised models of my data layer entities. I'm hitting difficulties when I put together the Create method for an entity (Foo) that's the principal of a one-to-many relationship with a set of dependent entities (Bar). I would like the consuming client application(s) to be able to use the returned model object to navigate from Foo to its collection of Bars, and from a given Bar to its parent Foo. Both sides of this relationship would appear to require model creation as follows:

```
public class ModelFactory
{
    public FooModel Create(Foo foo)
    {
        return new FooModel()
        {
            FooProperty1 = foo.FooProperty1,
            FooProperty2 = foo.FooProperty2,
            ...,
            Bars = foo.Bars.Select(b => Create(b)).ToList()
        };
    }

    public BarModel Create(Bar bar)
    {
        return new BarModel()
        {
            BarProperty1 = bar.Property1,
            BarProperty2 = bar.Property2,
            ...,
            Foo = Create(bar.Foo)
        };
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this results in an infinite loop with Foo creating Bars, which create subsequent Foos, and so on and so on. I've seen a couple of implementations where the many/dependent side of the relationship is returned without a reference to its parent object, which eliminates the problem, but I'd like to retain that linkage if possible.

Given that this is such a vanilla arrangement, I suspect that I'm completely missing the point somewhere. What's the right way to put this together?

Comment: You do know that `Select` will only call the `Create` function lazily, right?

Comment: I do now. Reviewing my code, the problem's being created by my handling of the IEnumerable return type from the Select statement. The Bars navigation property is an ICollection, so I've stuck on a ToList() after foo.Bars.Select(b => Create(b)) which is loading the Bars collection and causing the loop. Suspect the question needs amending at this point, will revise.

Comment: Well, it was just a side remark, it is not really germane to the issue at hand.

Comment: Nope, you're right. I've played around with a couple of notions on using/not using the ToList(), and it's not going to make any difference. Same loop/stackoverflow exception. Hmph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you ever create a `BarModel` without a parent `FooModel`? The first thing that comes to my mind is to simply require passing the parent `FooModel` into the `BarModel` `Create` method:

```
public class ModelFactory
{
    public FooModel Create(Foo foo)
    {
        var fooModel = new FooModel()
        { ... };

        // pass this model instance to the Create method
        fooModel.Bars = foo.Bars
              .Select(b => Create(b, fooModel))
              .ToList();

        return fooModel;
    }

    // how about making this private?
    // can a Bar exist without a Foo parent?
    private BarModel Create(Bar bar, FooModel parentModel)
    {
        return new BarModel()
        {
            // we don't create a new model here
            Foo = parentModel
        };
    }
}
```

On a side note, usual direction of the DAL-Entities dependency is to declare your entities (`FooModel`, `BarModel`) in your domain model, and have the DAL know about them and return instances of these actual entities. You can have data-specific DAOs (`Foo`, `Bar`) if you need them for the db access to work properly (although they are rarely needed if you're using an ORM framework), but they should be internal to the data layer, without the need to do these mappings inside your business logic.

Comment: Interesting. I'd been led to believe that returning my entities like that could lead to issues with overposting, hence the customised models

Comment: I'm going to accept this as the answer as it meets the brief for this limited use case. Sadly I don't think I can use it in my code. Bar is also the principal of another one-to-many with other entities, as those entities are with yet more entities. If I continue down this route I'm pretty sure I'll finish up with an almighty cascade of Creates which create my entire context on every call to the ModelFactory. Time for a rethink.

Comment: @goobering: There's usually no need to do this mapping at all. I don't know how you modeled your app architecture, but a great way to organize your web app is to use MVC with a Repository pattern (using an ORM framework under the hood). A skeleton for such app can be found [here](http://daveden.wordpress.com/2012/06/12/fluent-nhibernate-auto-mappings-asp-net-mvc-3-and-castle-windsor/) (it uses NH, but the same logic can be easily applied to EF).

Comment: That's a very handsome piece of work for retrieving data. It doesn't seem to address my concerns on clients overposting data back to the API. If I provide my entity models as-is to the client then there's nothing to prevent them from creating a new Foo when they post back a new Bar, or accessing properties I don't want them to have access to. See http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/model-validation-in-aspnet-web-api for an example.